# how to connect to oracle db using OCCI on linux?

Tags: linux, oracle, occi

I am trying to connect to oracle database (PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL.WORLD) from linux box (RHEL 6)  using OCCI (Oracle instantclient version 12.1 (latest)). I am getting tns error while connection. **tnsping works fine though.**  Could you please help in setting up correct configuration.  What am I missing here?

**Output**

```
[m499757@hkl20030996 bin]$ ./sqlplus toolkit/******@PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL.WORLD

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Thu May 22 12:32:56 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect
descriptor
```

Config details:

**Tnsnames.ora**

```
PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PHKLOD2001-xxxx.xx.hedani.net)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL)
    )
  )
```

**Odbc.ini**

```
[PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL]
Driver          = OracleODBC-12g
DSN             = OracleODBC-12g
ServerName      = PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL.WORLD
UserID          = toolkit
Password        = ******
```

**Odbcinst.ini**

```
[OracleODBC-12g]
Description     = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 12g
Driver          = /cs/gat/share/oracle/64/instantclient/libsqora.so.12.1
Driver64        = /cs/gat/share/oracle/64/instantclient/libsqora.so.12.1
FileUsage       = 1
Driver Logging  = 7
```

**LDAP.ora**

```
# LDAP.ORA Configuration
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=uk,dc=csfb,dc=com"
#DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=corpny,dc=csfb,dc=com"
DIRECTORY_SERVERS=     (oid_ldap_server_sg.sg.csfb.com:1522:1524,oid_ldap_server_ny.corpny.csfb.com:1522:1524,oid_l    dap_server_ln.csfp.co.uk:1522:1524)
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

**sqlnet.ora**

```
AUTOMATIC_IPC = OFF
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF
TCP.NODELAY = YES
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,LDAP,ONAMES,HOSTNAME)
names.default_domain = world
name.default_zone = world
```

Comment: Can you check if `ORACLE_SID=PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL sqlplus toolkit/******` works on the server?

Comment: gave my solution below.. i had to use service name instead of full SID. and it worked. I actually don't know why it worked though.

Answer (score 0):

Below wokred.

```
./sqlplus toolkit/******@PHK01200
```

And in my python script I used below connection string

```
"DRIVER={OracleODBC-12g}; Dbq=PHKLOD2001-scan.ap.hedani.net:1522/PHK01200_SECCOMPAS_APPL.WORLD"
```